# How do I concatenate single quotes in php?

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to create a simple sql statement in my php file, to insert two values into the database. Its throwing the error I implemented for non valid sql statements, and I believe its because the `VALUES( )` part is wrong. How do I concatenate the single quotes for the sql statement? The database values should be varchars.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_log_marcusw1(email_user, email_provider) "
 . "VALUES ('".$email_user."' , '".$email_provider."')";


mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {    
   echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the newline into the query?

Comment: why are you using "\n" in the query

Comment: What's the exact error mysql throws?

Comment: well this was the third "version" of my implementation and i just recently added the new line, the reason being was i used myphpadmin to create the insert statement and used their interface option to convert it to php and it had the new line in it.

Comment: the error is being thrown by the php code. its my own if statement that catches the error and its not very useful at all it does not tell anything about the code just that the sql statement im trying to create with php is invalid

Comment: are you calling `mysqli_query` twice by intention (is it in your code?) or just copied wrong?

Comment: yes its called twice in the php file. it was advised by a lab instructor at school to implement the error catching if statement

Comment: Can you send the SQL error?

Comment: SQL is not throwing the error.

Comment: but here is what i get when the user clicks submit

thanks for visiting! connection successfulError: INSERT INTO visitor_log_marcusw1(email_user, email_provider) VALUES ('example' , 'yahoo.com')

Comment: @LeonAdler you are correct to point out the method being called twice i removed it and now its submiting the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_log_marcusw1 (email_user, email_provider) VALUES ('{$email_user}' , '{$email_provider}')";
```

Also, there seems to be a typo with in the connection name ($conn vs $con).

Comment: thanks this seems like the most accurate way to concatenate the single quotes. but it still didnt work so it must be a problem with another part of the php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
```

Replace this with

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
```

$con not $conn

Answer (score -2):

Use mysql function **mysql_real_escape_string($php_variable)**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_log_marcusw1(email_user, email_provider) \n"
 . "VALUES (mysql_real_escape_string($email_user) , mysql_real_escape_string($email_provider)";
```

Comment: functions are not evaluated in strings.

Comment: It is a PHP function mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: that doesnt make sense because i would be sending sql a string with the php method in it.

Comment: $save_search_query_insert = "INSERT INTO user_search_query VALUES ($loggedInUserId, '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($query) . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($search_desc)  ."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE search_query = '"  . $mysqli->real_escape_string($query) . "', search_desc = '" .$mysqli->real_escape_string($search_desc). "'"  ;

I used this in my code and it worked for string containing special characters.